# Instead of appending values, pandas appends a column of NaNs. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why do I get NaN value when adding values in the b column and not for a?
This is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'grps': list('aaabbcaabcccbbc'), 
                   'vals': [12,345,3,1,45,14,4,52,54,23,235,21,57,3,87]})
                 
#extract all rows where a is present in the grps column

#for each a in a row, create an entry in a column (index 'a') in newdf from corresponding value on row 

newdf = pd.DataFrame()
newdf['a'] = df[df["grps"] == 'a']['vals']
#print(df[df["grps"] == 'b']['vals'])
newdf['b']=df[df["grps"] == 'b']['vals']

print(newdf)
```

This is the output:

```
     a   b
0   12 NaN
1  345 NaN
2    3 NaN
6    4 NaN
7   52 NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'grps': list('aaabbcaabcccbbc'), 
               'vals': [12,345,3,1,45,14,4,52,54,23,235,21,57,3,87]})
             
#extract all rows where a is present in the grps column

#for each a in a row, create an entry in a column (index 'a') in newdf from corresponding value on row 

newdf = pd.DataFrame()
newdf['a'] = df[df["grps"] == 'a']['vals'].values
#print(df[df["grps"] == 'b']['vals'])
newdf['b']=df[df["grps"] == 'b']['vals'].values

print(newdf)
```

The problem is that `df[df["grps"] == 'b']['vals']` is a `pd.Series` which is an index array and a value array, but `newdf` already has an index that it got from the previous line `newdf['a'] = df[df["grps"] == 'a']['vals']`. So when you do that twice, the indices are not matching anymore and pd does not know how to handle your command.

By adding the `.values` accessor you only append the values array, creating a default index which is now going to be just `[0,1,2,3,4]`